# Prefixing the description property using set-adcomputer

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm new to programming and I've decided to give powershell a shot, this is also my first post, so I'm not sure how much info to give, sorry in advance if I've gone overboard.

My problem is to try and identify a list of active directory workstations we administer inside an OU which is used for workstations across several areas of the business (each area has its own it dept but we share the same AD forest\OU) and modify the description property (which I've managed to do using a csv export of the dhcp vlan our machines are on and a bit of help/praying/watching mva stuff).

The problem I cant seem to get around is that I want to keep the existing description for a workstation, but prefix (or append if its easier) it with a new string (ie -Description  ("ORG-STACKOVERFLOW" - ).

I smashed together the script below to scrape with some basic comments, sorry if its horrible to read/not to standard. Basically the line I'm trying to play with is here:

```
Set-ADComputer $item.DNSHostName.Replace(".org.com.au","") -Description "ORG-STACKOVERFLOW" -Verbose -confirm
```

I think there is a method I can use to play with -description property, but I don't have the chops to figure it out. The only thing I could come up with was somehow creating another variable to store the existing description and then append it to the above command but then my brain starts to melt...

```
#Need to try and figure out if dhcp cmdlet can be used to scrape vlan for 
#this info, rather than use a manually generated list
$dhcp_data=import-csv -path C:\temp\<dhcp.csv> | sort DNSHostName

#Enter query after -match; ie "stackoverflow001":
$enames = $dhcp_data | Where-Object{$_.DNSHostName -match "stackov*"} 
$enames | Format-Table -AutoSize

#This function scrapes the AD OU for objects to update.
$ad_data = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=desktops,OU=workstations,OU=dept,DU=org,DC=com,DC=au" -Properties description | sort DNSHostName

#This function compares the dhcp list against the freshly generated list of AD objects
#looking at the DNSHostName column in both tables and generating a new table with matches
#in the $result variable. The $result1 variable filters the list again to only show a list 
#of matches ($results was inclulding empty results for some reason)
$result = Compare-Object $enames $ad_data -Property DNSHostName -IncludeEqual
$result1 = $result | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}
$result1


#This function looks at the data in each each row of the DNSHostName column in $result 
#and gives it a new description of "ORG-STACKOVERFLOW" if the data matches the query set 
#here: <{$_.DNSHostName -match "here"}>
ForEach ($item in $result1)
{ 
   Set-ADComputer $item.DNSHostName.Replace(".org.com.au","") -Description "ORG-STACKOVERFLOW" -Verbose -confirm
}
```

Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated! Even if its just how I could clean up my existing "code" a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the Description, you can use:

```
(Get-ADComputer $hostName -Properties Description).Description
```

or

```
Get-ADComputer $hostName -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
```

So, to store it in a variable:

```
$description = (Get-ADComputer $hostName -Properties Description).Description
```

You could perhaps do it all in one line with something like:

```
Set-ADComputer $hostName -Description "$((Get-ADComputer $hostName -Properties Description).Description)ORG-STACKOVERFLOW") -Verbose -confirm
```

But it's not easy to read so why bother?

When you're starting out with PowerShell, just do it a line at a time.  Don't try to write a whole script and then debug it.  Write a line to get your data.  Get it working.  Then manipulate the data, a bit.  Then a bit more.  When it's all as you want it, worry about putting the data somewhere.